# How to turn off Non-Type proposals only for new variables in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, autosuggest

When creating new variables, eclipse suggests names for them.
[image: popup]

However, I don't want to see any name suggestions unless if it is a variable that was already defined previously.

When turning off non-type proposals, it turns off ALL variable proposals, even the ones that were previously defined.
[image: popup]

I want ^ to still happen but not when creating new variables. Is this possible?

Comment: I am not aware of any preference for that. But it should be possible with a plugin (such as the one from Mylyn that filters proposals).